# Regression analysis of advertising expenditure, how to handle many zero values in predictors

Tags: multiple-regression

I'm working to create a Media Mix Model to determine the optimal mixture of media spend across multiple channels.

Trouble is the weekly data I have has many 0s. For example, TV spend will be consistent for a few weeks, then zero for 12 weeks. This pattern continues and is present in almost all the other 10 predictors.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: I don't see a problem.  If you are not spending on TV, then that is still useful data.

Comment: But is a linear regression still a good idea since the data is skewed towards zero?